What is the most efficient way of breaking out my data without exceeding packet limit using Transform Data with Power Query?
My current flow is as follows:

I'd like to make this flow more efficient with the following limitations:

I can't use SQL to filter - assume that I cannot have an on-prem gateway or anything of that sort.
I need to chunk out the full data. Create CSV Table gives me a limit error if I try to create tables 2023 and 2024. Let alone just 2 periods within one year. SO I have to go one period at a time per year.

Identifying the bottleneck:
In the Transform data using Power Query step, I run the entire query over again, and I use the concat function to feed in the current year and current period into the query.

I figured running the Power Query once outside the loop, and then filtering it through an array would work as like the screenshot below, however I can't compose a variable as I'm greeted with the following error:
message": "With compression algorithm, the compressed data size in a packet exceeds the max ServiceBus limit: GatewayCompressor - CompressedDataSize (16770404) of a non-compressed packet exceeds the maximum payload size of 8500000"



Just realizing the error I'm getting is actually from the Transform from Data with Power Query and not the Create CSV table:
With compression algorithm, the compressed data size in a packet exceeds the max ServiceBus limit: GatewayCompressor - CompressedDataSize (16832381) of a non-compressed packet exceeds the maximum payload size of 8500000.
